PDF viewer for android supporting hyperlink preview
I am looking for a pdf viewer for academic purposes. On laptop/Desktop, there are viewers like Evince/Sioyek which provide hyperlink preview. In other words, hovering over a hyperlink yields a preview of the hyperlinked portions. I find this feature to be super useful. Are there any viewers on Android which have some variant of this feature? (Of course, in Android, we do not have mouse hovering, but I imagine there may be a way of implementing this with long press? Thanks a lot!
